# If n is the biggest number that might not have a property, then n + 1 is the smallest number that must have the property. Do I need to prove it?

Tags: logic

Everything is in the question. I'm not talking about strictly a number, but rather an object and a property, let's say, $B$. Every object $O$ has a value assigned to it so that the function mapping objects to values is bijective. For simplicity's sake, let's say they are just numbers. If $n$ is the biggest number that *might* not have a property, the $n+1$ is the smallest number that must have that property. It's easy to see that's true, trivial I would say, but if I'm writing a paper using this fact, do I have to prove it? If yes, how do I do that?

P.S If a number has this property, then every number bigger than the number, has to have this property too.

Comment: Let $P$ be the said property. If $P(k)$  is true for all $k>n$ then $P(n+1)$ is true. If you want a rigorous explanation, read about The Well Ordering Principle, and The Principle of Mathematical Induction.

Comment: If your where writing a paper you wouldn't need to prove such property, which is a very well established fact. Nevertheless if you are a student who's learning how to build formal proofs then proving that fact could be a good exercise.

Comment: @Jacob1215 That's not what I meant. I know that. i just want to reframe the question, so that I don't have to look for the minimal number for which the property **has to** hold, but for the maximal number where I can build a counterexample.

Comment: @GiorgioMossa How would I go about proving it? Formal logic? I know some of it, but I have no idea, how to use it in such abstract examples.

Comment: @huB1erTi2hu actually I've just realized that the claim is false. That is way one should learn a to make formal (by that I mean rigorous) proofs. I will add a proof of the falsity of the claim.

Comment: "P.S If a number has this property, then every number bigger than the number, has to have this property too." This should be at the _beginning_ of the question, not at the end. It is the assumption on which your proof depends. The other thing you might need is a clear definition of what you mean by "might not have" and "must have".

Answer (score 0):

The claim is false.

Let $P(n)$ be the property

> $n$ is an odd number or $n > 10$
>   clearly the biggest number for which $P$ does not hold is $10$: it is an even number and it is not strctly greater than $10$, hence $P(10)$ is clearly false, and for every $k> 10$ clearly $P(k)$ holds.

Nevertheless the smallest number $n$ for which $P(n)$ holds it is not $11=10+1$, but it is $1$, because it is odd.

The problem is due in the fact that in your hypothesis

> $n$ is the biggest that does not have the property $P$

you are requiring that $n$ is the biggest element of the set 
$$\{k \in \mathbb N\colon P(k) \text{ does not hold}\}$$ 
but there is no reason in general for suspecting that if a property $P$ does not hold for a given $n$ then it should not hold also forall $k < n$.

So there could be a $k < n$ for which $P(n)$, i.e. which does not belong to the set above, and the smallest element for which $P$ holds should be smaller (not necessarily strictly) of such $k$.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Besides there is also another counter example. Since you have that $n$ *might be* the biggest number for which the property doesn't hold, it *might* also happen that for this $n$ the property $P$ holds and also in this case the smallest number for which $P$ holds should be smaller or equal to $n$.

Comment: Yeah, well I forgot to add that if $P(n)$ is false then $b<n\implies\lnot  P(b)$. It is actually kind of trivial

Comment: @huB1erTi2 it is not actually, there are lots of properties which do not verify that requirements. For instance lots of analysis' properties which are definitively true.